# A page I made was fine last night but now only shows me black and red

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: It was something like this.]
[image: Now it looks like this.]

I don't know what I did wrong.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nle_app/models/stall.dart';
import 'package:nle_app/constants/colors.dart';

class StallInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  final stall = Stall.generateRestaurant();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    stall.name,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.4),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            stall.label,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          )),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                child: Image.asset(
                  stall.logoUrl,
                  width: 80,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                stall.desc,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.star_outline,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${stall.score}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 15),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The image I uploaded shows what its suppossed to look like but in case you missed it, it's supposed to look like [image: this.].
I thought maybe the image overflowed to the right but even when I remove the image it's the same thing.
I've tested it on different devices but it's all the same. It doesn't even throw an exception or anything. Does anyone know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is missing material, Check if the parent widget contains `Scaffold`. Also for this one , you can wrap with any material widget like `Material`, `Card`,`Scaffold`....

````dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
       child: Container(
    
```
````

Comment: I didn't even notice that was missing. But I'm sure I put it the first time. I used pushNamed to send the user to this page so, could it be what removed it? Or is someone trolling me?

Comment: While using push, use scaffold on new page, this is more general case.

Comment: I'm getting a new error: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

Comment: There are few cases to produce this, check if it is containing expanded inside scrollable widget. Try to create a new question with minimal reproducible example.